# Wann beschreibt das Perfekt die Zukunft?

Tags: tense, perfect-tense

Normalerweise beschreibt das Perfekt die Vergangenheit. Ich habe aber diese Konstruktion gelernt:

> Nachdem ich gegessen habe, schlafe ich.

So sagt man vor dem Essen. Gibt es andere Konstruktionen, abgesehen von *nachdem*, in denen das Perfekt die Zukunft beschreibt?

Comment: Die Bedeutung des Satzes ist nicht eindeutig. Es kann sich um ein einmaliges Ereignis oder auch um eine Gewohnheit handeln. Für ein einmaliges Ereignis in der Zukunft würde ich es nicht verwenden

Answer (score 3):

Ohne weiteren Kontext bezieht sich das nicht notwendigerweise auf die Zukunft. Ich interpretiere den Satz so:

> Nach jedem Essen (in der Vergangenheit oder Zukunft) schlafe ich.

Comment: I see. You could assume that it would be clear from the context in this question.

Answer (score 3):

> Sobald ich gegessen habe, gehe ich schlafen.

Man kann auch sagen

> Sobald ich gegessen habe, werde ich schlafen gehen.

Das *sobald* bezieht sich, genau wie *nachdem*, auf einen Zeitpunkt. Zu diesem Zeitpunkt liegt die Aktion jedoch in der Vergangenheit, steht daher im Perfekt. Diese Beispiele würde ich aber anders herum sagen:

> Ich gehe schlafen, sobald/wenn/nachdem ich gegessen habe.

Answer (score 1):

Hier gibt es wohl beliebig viele Möglichkeiten, beispielsweise:

> Nachdem ich gekocht habe, esse ich.
>
> Nachdem ich mich rasiert habe, dusche ich.

EDIT: Möglich ist auch:

> Bald habe ich es aufgegessen. (Anstatt Futur II: Bald werde ich es aufgegessen haben.)
>
> Morgen habe ich geduscht.

Comment: Genau, aber ich suche _andere_ Konstruktionen. Ich will die Frage erklären.

Comment: *"Morgen habe ich geduscht"* klingt ziemlich komisch in meinen Ohren.

Comment: "Morgen habe ich geduscht." drückt aus, dass man am darauffolgenden Tag geduscht haben wird, was man an dem Tag auf den sich der Satz bezieht offenbar nicht getan hat.

Comment: Grammatikalisch besser wäre es aber in der vollendeten Zukunft (Futur II): „Morgen werde ich geduscht haben.“

Comment: Schriftsprachlich sollte man auch Futur II benutzen.

Comment: @deceze: Morgen um die selbe Zeit habe ich bereits geduscht  (weil ich nämlich morgen früher aufstehen werde). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Nachdem ich gegessen habe, schlafe ich.
>
> So sagt man vor dem Essen.

I don't think it's *Perfekt* but *Futur II*. As in many languages in colloquial speech lots of "redundant information" can be omitted. If you say so *before or during* supper everybody will know, what you mean. It's made pretty clear by the situation and `nachdem`.

> Nachdem ich gegessen habe[n werde], schlafe ich.

You could use other variations to make clear that you are talking about smth you are going to do **after finishing supper.**

> Wenn ich aufgegessen habe[n werde], schlafe ich.

Answer (score -1):

***Gibt es andere Konstruktionen in denen das Perfekt die Zukunft beschreibt?***

---

Umgangssprachlich wird das Perfekt oft anstatt eines Futur-Perfekt verwendet:

> - Wenn sie bis morgen Mittag nicht angerufen haben, dann werde ich...

Grammatikalisch richtig - aber viel träger - ist die Konstruktion:

> - Wenn sie bis morgen Mittag nicht angerufen haben werden, dann werde ich...

---

Prinzipiell muss man immer zwischen zwei Varianten unterscheiden:

> - Eine allgemeine Aussage, die sich zeitlos auf jeden Zusammenhang beziehen kann
>     (Nachdem ich gegessen habe, schlafe ich immer ein wenig)
> - Etwas in der Art meines Beispielssatzes, das sich auf einen bestimmten Zeitpunkt bezieht

---

Noch zu sagen wäre auch, dass das Futur Perfekt auch für Vermutungen verwendet wird, die sich auf die Vergangenheit beziehen:

> - Sie werden ihren Sommerurlaub bestimmt schon beendet haben - es ist ja schon fast Herbst!

Natürlich funktioniert hier auch das Perfekt (Vermutung in der Gegenwart):

> - Sie haben ihren Urlaub wohl schon beendet! Ich habe sie nämlich gestern gesehen...

---

Prinzipiell sollte man jedes Zeitensystem von zwei Seiten her betrachten:

- absolut
- relativ

**'Absolute Zeiten'** sind nur *Vergangenheit*, *Gegenwart* und *Zukunft*, wobei mit der Gegenwart sehr vorsichtig umzugehen ist - denn in Wirklichkeit existiert auch sie (fast) nicht! Jedes Ereignis liegt schon lange in der Zukunft bevor es eintritt, die Gegenwart existiert nur einen Bruchteil einer Sekunde und dann ist alles schon wieder Vergangenheit - für ewig.

Das *'grammatikalische'* Konstrukt '*Gegenwart*' lässt uns die verschiedensten zeitunabhängigen Dinge beschreiben:

- Ich mache ***gerade*** etwas...
- ***Normalerweise*** mache ich etwas...
- ***Morgen*** mache ich etwas anderes...

**'Relative Zeiten'** sind *[Präsens-]Perfekt* (Vollendete Gegenwart), *Plusquamperfekt* (Vollendete Vergangenheit), *Futur-Perfekt* (Vollendete Zukunft).

Deshalb fällt es uns auch so leicht das oben gesagte sowohl mit einem Perfekt als auch mit Futur-Perfekt auszudrücken (Ökonomieprinzip). Dieses findet man in vielen anderen Sprachen auch!

Englisch hat eine glücklichere Hand mit einer sehr konsistenten Benennung dieses Konzepts:

> **Present**-(Tense) vs. **Present-Perfect**-(Tense)
>   **Past**-(Tense) vs. **Past-Perfect**-(Tense)
>   **Future**-(Tense) vs. **Future-Perfect**-(Tense)

---

Etwas passiert ***'vorzeitig - gleichzeitig - nachzeitig'*** ! Das hat nicht unmittelbar etwas mit ***'Vergangenheit - Gegenwart - Zukunft'*** zu tun. Zukunft ist immer nachzeitig, Vergangenheit immer vorzeitig - im Bezug auf eine flüchtige Gegenwart - aber nicht umgekehrt. 'Nachzeitig' ist nicht immer Zukunft (absolute Zukunft)!

*'Romanische Sprachen'* verwenden Modi und relative Zeiten viel extensiver als die deutsche Sprache. Ein Subjunktiv-Imperfekt (Konjunktiv ähnlich) kann z.B aussagen, dass etwas nachher passiert, also in der Zukunft, aber gesehen vom Standpunkt der Vergangenheit aus...

> - Ich wollte dich solange begleiten, bis das Taxi kommen würde (wir wussten nicht, wann es kommen würde)

Im Gegensatz zu nur:

> - Ich begleitete Dich solange, bis das Taxi kam. (wir wissen wann es kam)

---

Wenn du also sagst:

> *'Normalerweise beschreibt das Perfekt die Vergangenheit...'*

stimmt das in mehreren Belangen nicht ganz. In der Hochsprache und im Schriftdeutsch verwendet man das Imperfekt um Ereignisse aus der Vergangenheit zu beschreiben. Dinge die man öfter oder wiederholend gemacht hat. Es ist eigentlich keine gute aktive Erzähl-Zeit, die eine Handlung frisch und zügig fortschreiten lässt, also eher statisch! Leider fehlt uns hier eine zusätzliche Zeitform um diese Aktivitäten auszudrücken, deshalb wird auch im Alltag so viel mit Imperfekt und Perfekt herumgemischt, ohne eigentlich ein wirkliches Konzept zu verfolgen. Wir nennen das dann aus Verlegenheit 'lokale' Unterschiede in der Anwendungen von Zeitformen :-)

> Im Gegensatz eine 'Vollendeten Gegenwart' (Perfekt)
>
> ***'Schau mal, ich habe das gerade eben fertig gemacht'***
>
> (->  ***'Ich machte das gerade fertig '*** klingt ziemlich blöd...)

---

Wenn man ***Sprache*** im Zusammenhang mit ***Zeit*** betrachten will ist man besser dran, wenn man die '*absoluten*' und '*relativen*' Zeiten als zwei getrennte Konzepte betrachtet!

Comment: Ich halte die Konstruktion, die Du "richtig, aber träger" nennst, für schlichtweg falsch.

Comment: @CarstenS: Siehe weiter unten in den Kommentaren -> '*Morgen habe ich geduscht*' - hier brauchst du das '*träge*' Futur-Perfekt um die relative Vorzeitigkeit korrekt zu kommunizieren. Sobald du eine genauere Zeitangabe hinzufügst z.B. '***bis** Morgen*', '*Morgen ... **dann schon***', '*Morgen ... **bereits***' usw. reicht dann auch das Perfekt weil Du eindeutig klarstellst, dass es sich um ein 'relatives' Zeitverhältnis  handelt. Man kann also 'Sprachökonomie' walten und vorherrschen lassen. Jedoch ist die Futur-Perfekt Version - wenn auch 'träge' - absolut korrekt!